# Disable User Selection in <h:selectOneRadio>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-1.2

I am trying to disable user selection in  tag.

```
    <h:selectOneRadio id="wildcard"   value="#{NewService.isWildCard}" label="#{msg.org_IsWildCard}" readonly="true" layout="lineDirection">              
                                        <f:selectItem id="yes" itemLabel="YES" itemValue="1" />
                                        <f:selectItem id="no" itemLabel="NO" itemValue="0" />                                       
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

However on my GUI I am still able to select radio button value.
Please tell me what is wrong in the code..Also the BackingBean code is pretty simple..I am just passing 0 or 1 in backingBean...

Please guide me on how to disable user selection in

Comment: Are you using JSF 2.0 or JSF 1.2? Please fix your tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is indeed unintuitive behaviour of the JSF-generated HTML `<input type="radio">` element. There are basically 2 solutions to your problem:

1. Use `disabled="true"` instead of `readonly="true"`:

   ```
   <h:selectOneRadio disabled="true">
   ```
2. Add an onclick handler which returns false:

   ```
   <h:selectOneRadio onclick="return false;">
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `itemDisabled` attribute in your selectItems:

```
<f:selectItem id="yes" itemLabel="YES" itemValue="1" itemDisabled="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="wildcard"   value="#{NewService.isWildCard}" label="#{msg.org_IsWildCard}" readonly="true" layout="lineDirection">              
     <f:selectItem id="yes" itemLabel="YES" itemValue="1" itemDisabled="#{NewService.type == 1 }"/>
     <f:selectItem id="no" itemLabel="NO" itemValue="0" itemDisabled="#{NewService.type == 1 }"/>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```