# How to Freeze JSF Radio Buttons

Tags: jsf

i have the following jsf code:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{ref.arrive.boardingInformation}">
      <f:selectItems value="#{newMessage.boardingInformationSelectItemList}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Is it possible to freeze this kind of selectradiobutton in that way, that my user can´t change the value?

This radiobuttons are only for reading and not for writing or changing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable User Selection in <h:selectOneRadio>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496859/disable-user-selection-in-hselectoneradio)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{ref.arrive.boardingInformation}" disabled="true">
      <f:selectItems value="#{newMessage.boardingInformationSelectItemList}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Here are the available properties: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_selectoneradio_tag.htm

Comment: Might not work in all browsers, IE 7 doesn't support that as far as I remember

Comment: Please refer the official documentation instead of a 3rd party site which contains potentially bad/misleading content. Here's the official documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/selectOneRadio.html